# Python cv2 TypeError: src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

The following code gives the error: ""TypeError: src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar"" by using cv2.The image is defined as Grey level image with photoimage. The image is displayed correctly and I don't understand why it doesn't work.

```
    #Photoimage
    self.imgTk=ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    #label the image
    label = Tk.Label(self.canvasright,image=self.imgTk)
    label.image = self.imgTk # keep a reference!
    label.pack()

    #img.save('img_gif','gif')     
    #imgTk=ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)#('img_gif')
    #PhotoImage(master = self.canvasright, width = WIDTH, height = HEIGHT)
    #self.canvasright.image=self.imgTk
    #self.canvasright.create_image(0,0,image=label,anchor=Tk.NW)
    #self.canvasright.pack()

def find_balls(self):
    imggray=cv2.cvtColor(self.imgTk, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    self.circles = cv2.HoughCircles(imggray,cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,
                        param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=200)
    print self.circles
```

Answer (score 0):

For opencv You need to pass the image as numpy array

In your function def find_balls(self): do the following

Add a line immediately inside the function

```
def find_balls(self):

    #Add this Line
    temp_image = cv2.imread(self.imgTk)
    #This will read the image and convert it to a numpy array 
    #Now replace the first parameter(self.imgTk to temp_image) in the next line
    imggray=cv2.cvtColor(temp_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    self.circles = cv2.HoughCircles(imggray,cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,
                    param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=200)
    print self.circles
```